# How do I make a 2D texture into a banner/flag that looks like it is folding from a breeze?

Tags: gimp, inkscape

I've got a 2D image and I want to transform it into something that looks like a single frame from an animation of that logo on fabric catching just a bit of breeze. I'm not an artist so don't have Photoshop or Illustrator, just free stuff like GIMP and Inkscape (under Windows)

I know it's some kind 3D transform (or a cheap simulation using filters) - but I don't know the technique. Honestly, I don't know what keywords to use to search Google/YouTube to find what I need.

Ideally, something like this (though less drastic) from a flat image:[image]

But something even more fake/subtle like this would be OK: [image]

Perhaps techniques for both?

***Update***
Here's a photo with some of my results using the water simulator mentioned in the selected answer:

[image: Iron Circle flags on The Iron Keep]

Comment: if possible post a image of your desired output, it would be easy to guess or give you something duplicate with gimp.

Comment: Done. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [stock.xchng](http://www.sxc.hu/blog/post/1284):

> 1. open up a flat image of a flag in GIMP. Make sure that there is either transparency showing around it, or that it is on it's own layer and it does not cover the entire screen.
> 2. Select the layer with the flag on it and open Filters->Distorts->Curve Bend
>      Check 'Automatic Preview'
>      In the modify curve box, play with the curve until it looks right.
>      Switch the Curve for Border to Lower, and basically make the lines align.
>      Click OK
> 3. Duplicate the Layer
> 4. Draw black lines on where the flag curves up the most
> 5. Apply Filters->Blur->Gaussian Blur
>
>    The default setting of 5 horizontal and 5 vertical should be good unless the image is  really high quality. Then you would need to increase it.
> 6. Lower the opacity until it looks right (In the layers dialog box)

And your done...

running out of time if  possible i'll show you with screenshots in my next edit

see this also :

- [Realistic flag](http://www.aagimp.com/2008/12/gimp-tutorial-realistic-flag-2-amazing.html)
- [Realistic flag 2](http://www.aagimp.com/2008/12/gimp-tutorial-realistic-flag-2-amazing.html)
- [wave plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24330)

hope it will help...

Comment: I was able to duplicate both the manual technique and to quickly find a setting for the wave plugin that produced awesome results! Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Dodge/Burn tools](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-dodge-burn.html). You can see a video tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT_tTDaYEOU) that explains how to use it, though not with a flag. You should be able to figure it out fairly quickly, though.

Comment: I'm not getting that video - I don't understand what "dodge" and "burn" mean and how I would use those to get the effect desired.